# Recreating Python's input statement in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to recreate Python's `input()` statement in Swift, I have seen some examples, but I am trying to make it better, firstly, my version removes the `\n` part of the string, also, I was trying to make it firstly print a prompt, so that `var example = input()` would just wait for the message, (which it does), but then `var example = input("Enter text: ")` would print `Enter text:` and wait for text to be inputed.

The problem is, swift seems to be messing up the print's order. For example, being the code:

```
import Foundation

func input(inputStatement: String? = nil) -> String {
    if let inputStatement = inputStatement {
        print(inputStatement, terminator:"")
    }
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    var strData = NSString(data: inputData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
    strData = strData.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "")
    print()
    return strData
}

print("Creating the input statement in Swift!")
var test = input("What's your name: ")
print("You entered: \(test).")
```

And the input text, "hi", this prints:

```
Creating the input statement in Swift!
hi
What's your name: You entered: hi.
```

And what I expected was:

```
Creating the input statement in Swift!
What's your name: hi
You entered: hi.
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: print("What's your name: \(test).")

Comment: @Lion No, I don't want to print it, I want it to print the inputStatement with a terminator of "", so that when I write the input, it will write after the prompt. And I'm quite sure that if I wanted to do that, it would be: `print("What's your name: \(test).")`, not `print("What's your name: (test).")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the standard output file descriptor is *line buffered*
when writing to a terminal (and fully buffered otherwise).
Therefore the output of

```
print(inputStatement, terminator:"")
```

is buffered and not written before the

```
print()
```

writes a newline. You can fix that by flushing the file 
descriptor explicitly:

```
if let inputStatement = inputStatement {
    print(inputStatement, terminator:"")
    fflush(stdout)
}
```

Note also that there is a

```
public func readLine(stripNewline stripNewline: Bool = default) -> String?
```

which reads a line from standard input, with the option to
remove the trailing newline character. This function also
flushes standard output. Therefore a simpler implementation would be

```
func input(prompt: String = "") -> String {
    print(prompt, terminator: "")
    guard let reply = readLine(stripNewline: true) else {
        fatalError("Unexpected EOF on input")
    }
    return reply
}
```

(Of course you might choose to handle "end of file" differently.)